# How to send MQ message with correct format via Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, connection, ibm-mq

We're building a new project where we need to inject message in IBM MQ via Jmeter. We've installed the relevant mq jars & configured the script with Java request in jmeter. The connection was successful but then we found the XML we're sending is going in text format including CDATA. How to configure proper message format using this configuration?[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. We don't know what format is "correct". As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)

   > The design goals of XML emphasize simplicity, generality, and usability across the Internet.[6] It is a **textual data format** with strong support via Unicode for different human languages.

   so XML **is text** hence your "expectations" are quite unclear
2. We don't know what is the format your plugin is producing
3. We don't know what is the plugin you're using.

If this is [mqmeter](https://github.com/JoseLuisSR/mqmeter) - you can reach out to the plugin developers via Github or raise an [issue](https://github.com/JoseLuisSR/mqmeter/issues)

Another option is using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) where you will have full freedom regarding what, where and how to send, see [IBM MQ testing with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-testing-with-jmeter-learn-how) article for more details if needed

Comment: The format here we need to send is MQSTR. Like we use http header manager for providing the header for http request, here also we need to send some header. But we don't find any filed to provide the value for the header. Also this is the error received at the mq end while we are sending the request: Caused by:org.xml.sax.SAXParsexception; unexpected element CDATA